# Power Automate flow convert string to interger

Tags: type-conversion, integer, power-automate

Im looking for simple proces how to convert string to interger.

from `Select - Data operation` i have this Output:

```
[
    "221526.00000000",
    "221527.00000000"

]
```

what is right Expression to convert this output to integer ?

when i use expression:

```
int(body('Select'))
```

or

```
float(body('Select')
```

Got this error

`error`

```
Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Compose' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'int' was invoked with a parameter that is not valid. The value cannot be converted to the target type.'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is an array you would need to use an index [0] to refer to a specific item (even if it is just one item).

Try:

```
int(body('Select')[0])
```

Comment: what about if there will be more then item ? how to change Expression ?

Comment: In that case you can also convert it directly in the select action itself in the Map field. That would be something like below: `int(item()?['fieldname'])`